# Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: h. Path '', line 0, position 0

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-webapi, blazor-webassembly

I am trying to display the URL of the selected image to be uploaded. However, when I run the program it tells me `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: h. Path '', line 0, position 0.` and that there is an issue with the parsing in the deserialization. However, I do not see any issues with the deserialization. Am I not seeing something that is causing this? The web api returns the `AbsoluteUri` for my file that has been uploaded which I made it into a string... so it returns `var absoluteUrl = blob.Uri.AbsoluteUri.ToString();`.

```
  private async Task<HttpResponseMessage> UploadFileSelected()
        {
            // Create the content
            var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
            content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("form-data");

            content.Add(new StreamContent(fileStream, Convert.ToInt32(fileStream.Length)), "file", fileName);

            string url = "https://localhost:5011";

            var response = await _httpClient.PostAsync($"{url}/api/fileupload", content);
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            var responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<HttpResponseMessage>(responseContent);

            message = "Uploaded!!";

            fileurl = responseContent;

            Console.Write("result: " + result);

            Console.WriteLine("url: " + fileurl);

            return await Task.FromResult(result);
        }
```

Endpoint:

```
[HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Upload()
        {
            try
            {
                var formCollection = await Request.ReadFormAsync();
                var file = formCollection.Files.First();

                if (file.Length > 0)
                {
                    var container = new BlobContainerClient(_azureConnectionString, "container");
                    var createResponse = await container.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();
                    if (createResponse != null && createResponse.GetRawResponse().Status == 201)
                        await container.SetAccessPolicyAsync(PublicAccessType.Blob);

                    var blob = container.GetBlobClient(file.FileName);
                    await blob.DeleteIfExistsAsync(DeleteSnapshotsOption.IncludeSnapshots);

                    using (var fileStream = file.OpenReadStream())
                    {
                        await blob.UploadAsync(fileStream, new BlobHttpHeaders { ContentType = file.ContentType });
                    }   

                    var absoluteUrl = blob.Uri.AbsoluteUri.ToString();

                    Console.WriteLine(absoluteUrl);

                    return Ok(absoluteUrl);
                }

                return BadRequest();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return StatusCode(500, $"Internal server error: {ex}");
            }
        }
```

[image]

Comment: show your endpoint code at `/api/fileupload`. you're responding with something that isn't JSON.

Comment: @Andy Please see the updated post, I have included the endpoint code.

Comment: at the top of your controller, where it says `[ApiController]`, change it to `[ApiController, Produces("application/json")]`

Comment: Also, change `var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<HttpResponseMessage>(responseContent);` to `var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string>(responseContent);`

Comment: This worked! Thank you! So the `Produces("application/json")` makes the controller return it into json objects?

Comment: Yes -- It handles all the serialization for you

Comment: That's pretty impressive that it does just from that. Good to know, thanks again for your help!

Comment: deep under the covers there are `JsonOutputFormatter` objects injected in to controllers that are bound to that specific mime-type. Glad it worked out!